# What is wrong with my code of reversing each word of a given string in java?

Tags: java, string, reverse

After submission it says the answer is wrong, please tell me what is the logical error in it and not about the formatting or other ways to do it.

```
public class Solution {
  public static String reverse(String s1){
    int i=s1.length()-1;
    String s2="";
    while(i>=0){
        s2=s2+s1.charAt(i--);     
    }
    s2=s2+' ';
    return s2;
  }
    // Return the reversed string. No need to print

  public static String reverseEachWord(String s1) {
      s1=s1+"";
    String s2="";
    int i=0;
    char ch;
    String temp="";
    while(i<s1.length()){
      ch=s1.charAt(i);
      if(ch!=' '){
        temp=temp+ch;
        i++;  
      }
      else{
        temp=reverse(temp);
        s2=s2+temp;
        temp="";
        i++;
      }
    }
    return s2;  
    }
}
```

Comment: *What is wrong with my code of reversing each word of a given string in java?* How about giving us a hint?  Maybe it is because of the terrible formatting of your code?

Comment: What is the issue? Why? What were you expecting? What happened instead? Is there any error? If yes, please post the stack trace.

Comment: result string is empty

Comment: You're collecting each word of string `s1` into `temp`;  once you've got a whole word in `temp` you then reverse _something_ and append the reversed _something_ onto `s2`.  But I think you reversed the wrong _something_...

Comment: `int j = 0;` doesn't do anything in the first method. For the second method the easiest implementation is to just call `s1.Split(' ')` to get an array of words then apply the first method to each word and stich everything back together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reverseWord function has some logical bugs, please update your function to :
Change

`s1 = s1 +"";`

To

```
s1 = s1 + " ";
```

As you need to concatenate space.

Instead of if you can use a while loop which can further simplify your code.

```
public static String reverseEachWord(String s1) {

    s1 = s1 + " ";
    String s2 = "";
    int i = 0;
    char ch;
    String temp = "";
    while (i < s1.length()) {

        while (s1.charAt(i) != ' ') {
            temp = temp + s1.charAt(i);
            i++;
        } 
        temp = reverse(temp);
        s2 = s2 + temp;
        temp = "";
        i++;

    }

    return s2;

}
```

Comment: showing runtime error

Comment: @vss works fine. Please have a look : https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/UwMN7p1dVB

Comment: yes, thankyou. can you tell me what is the logical error in my while loop?

Comment: @vss basically line temp = reverse(s2); and  s1=s1+"" ; was the root cause of unexpected behaviour.  :-)

Comment: yes but i changed temp=reverse(temp) still it was wrong but i dont understand why

Comment: Also change s1 = s1 + "" to s1 = s1 + " ". your code will work fine. You need to concatenate space to s1.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry to say but I see a lot of issues.

- Firstly, I suggest that you should use StringBuilder next time when you
  manipulate String frequently.
- Secondly, If s1 is a single word not a sentence like  s1 = "question", in your case it will be store in the temp and your while loop ends. s2 is still empty and you got a wrong answer. What's more, if s1 is a sentence with many words, the last word will have the same issue as mentioned above.
- And there is a mistake in this line `temp = reverse(s2);` Your s2 is empty at the very begining, and it will stay that way. I suppose you want to write `temp = reverse(temp);`

BTW, I didn't run your code and for now I only got these issues in your code.

Comment: i would like to do it this way, and yes that was the mistake temp = reverse(s2); but even after the answer is still wrong

Comment: Did you fix the first two issues?

Comment: Read again plz.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of other way to do this. But if you want to change in your code then here it is

```
public static String reverseEachWord(String s1) {

        s1 = s1 + " ";
        String s2 = "";
        int i = 0;
        char ch;
        String temp = "";
        while (i < s1.length()) {
            ch = s1.charAt(i);
            if (ch != ' ') {
                temp = temp + ch;
                i++;
            } else {
                temp = reverse(temp);
                s2 = s2 + temp;
                temp = "";
                i++;
            }

        }

        return s2;

    }
```

> change from temp = reverse(s2); to temp = reverse(temp);

Comment: did, wrong answer still